# Google Charts - Not drawing Chart - Data table is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, google-visualization

I set an Interval with Ajax for my Google Chart but the Chart isnt being drawn. I only get the message: "Data table is not defined." every 5 seconds. [Picture of the Meessage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KM8Q.png)

Google Chart Source:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
setInterval(drawChart, 5000);

function load_page_data(){
 $.ajax({
    url: 'getTemp.php',
    type: 'get',
    success: function (json) {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($table); ?>);


       var options = {
        title: 'Raspberry:',
        curveType: 'function',
        'height':400
    };
    },
    });
}
     function drawChart() {
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw();

     }

 </script>
```

PHP File that gets the Data from MySQL:

```
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   try {
   $result = $conn->query('SELECT * 
   FROM Device_Data ');



    $rows = array();
   $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(array('label' => 'Timestamp', 'type' => 'string'),array('label' => 'Temperature', 'type' => 'number'),array('label' => 'Humidity', 'type' => 'number'));

   foreach($result as $r) {

   $data = array();
   $data[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Timestamp']);
   $data[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Temperature']);
   $data[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Humidity']);

   $rows[] = array('c' => $data);

   }

  $table['rows'] = $rows;

 } catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }

 try {
   $result2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT 'Temperature','Humidity', 'Timestamp'  from Device_Data;");      

  $result2->execute();

 } catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in chart.draw(); u have to provide the datatable and options

```
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Comment: thanks that worked, the "Data table is not defined" Message is gone now. Only problem is now that i get another Error Message (Uncaught ReferenceError: dataTable is not defined
    at drawChart) and the chart is still not being drawn.

Comment: Do one thing ..dont write seperate function drawChart()

Comment: Add the code  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw();   after options...check if it works

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: drawChart is not defined
    at data.php:27

Comment: Oh that is because now u have removed the drawChart function

Comment: I removed the drawChart function completly now but now i get no Error Message of any sort and the chart is still not being drawn.